# Are Google Compute Engine Load Balancers Highly Available?

Tags: load-balancing, google-compute-engine

Maybe this is an obvious questions but I didn't find it stated explicitly anywhere. In contrast Linode load balancers are explicitly documented as [highly available](https://www.linode.com/docs/platform/nodebalancer/getting-started-with-nodebalancers).
Any guess?

Answer (score 3):

Google Compute Engine Load Balancers is highly available and fault tolerant service. You don't need to worry about scaling it, failing over to a backup node if something goes wrong etc as you would if you'd need to manage the load balancer yourself.

It doesn't mean it has 100% SLA. Just like any other part of Google Cloud Platform it is covered by 99.95% SLA which means it can be unavailable for a duration of 4h 22m per year without being considered as SLA breach.